Is my front brake caliper mounted correctly using the adapter?
I have bought a Cube Nuroad Race second-hand from a person I know, that doesn't really tinker around with their bikes, but I have a weird feeling about the mount of the front brake caliper. How you can see on the picture it doesn't seem like it is using the whole width of the disk and instead some parts of the break pads hang over the edge.
I am pretty sure that everything is how the dealer assembled the bike and that should mean that everything is correct, but I would love if some of you could confirm that.
My rotor has a diameter of 160mm
Thanks!





Are you sure this is a 160mm rotor. Can you post a picture that confirms this pls?

@ArtGertner I added the picture that confirms the 160mm size

I'll just add here a comment from a deleted answer, that may be useful for future readers:  In some gravel bikes (I knew it for the Specialized Diverge, the Nuroad seems to be in that batch as well), the front mount is a bit shifted, the idea being to use the same mounting plates as 140/160 rotors, but to use them with 160/180mm rotors. But it's very confusing, at least this plate indicates the two options: on my bike (Diverge) the plate must be at the 140mm orientation for 160mm rotor, and at the 160mm orientation for 180mm rotor. A too small rotor is a possible answer, but not in this case.

Shimano has two types of rotor (and the matching brake pads): narrow and wide. The narrow/wide refers to the part of the rotor that is in contact with the pads. Wide ones are used on entry-level flat bar bikes, narrow ones on mid-range to high-range flat bar components, and road components.
The rotor you have is a "wide" one, but GRX calipers and pads are "narrow", but according to Shimano's compatibility chart, it's OK (as long as you are using resin pads, metallic pad are not compatible with this rotor - but that's a bit outside the scope of the question).

That explains the "narrow" use marks on the rotor... Thank you!
